# Linq query with month difference between 2 dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 Field FromDate and ToDate in database. I want the result LINQ query for records that have month difference of 2 dates with some dynamic value.

Actually I have one database table as EmploymentHistory with field NameOfCompany as nvarchar(50), ProfileID as bigint, EmoploymentFrom as datetime, EmploymentUpto as datetime, IsCurrentEmployer as bit.

ProfileID is reference key of Profile
I want to generate a query for all profiles by experience in month.

if IsCurrentEmployer is true then EmploymentUpto is null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're under .NET 4+ you could try [`EntityFunctions.DiffMonths`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd382850.aspx) utility method e.g.:

```
var query = query
            .Where(i=> 
                 EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(i.FromDate, i.ToDate) == 2
            );
```

Comment: `EntityFunctions` has now been replaced with `DbFunctions`

Answer (score 2):

Asuming you are using entity framework.. u may

```
Query(q => q.ToDate < DateTime.Today && q.FromDate > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2))
```

Query is any Iqueryable.. could be select, first, firstOrDefault..
of course you can change *DateTime.Today* to yours params.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute this code

```
var resultWithMonth = datevalue2.Subtract(datevalue2).Days / (365.25 / 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you pull the dates out of the db, you can perform a zip operation with the subtract func as the selection argument.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> datesA = //blah;
IEnumerable<DateTime> datesB = //blah;
IEnumerable<DateTime> differences = 
  datesA.Zip( datesB, (dA,dB) => dA.Subtract(dB));
```